# Totally ordered set whose every element has an immediate successor and predecessor

Tags: order-theory

Are there characterizations of this kind of ordering? Or at least, how is it called? Note that this is not necessarily a well-order. For instance, this kind of ordering on the set of integers: 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < ... < -3 < -2 < -1.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, these orderings can be completely classified.  Given such an ordering $X$, define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by $x\sim y$ if $x$ is the $n$th successor of $y$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (for negative $n$ this means $x$ is an iterated predecessor of $y$).  Then the set $Y$ of equivalence classes of $\sim$ itself is totally ordered, by $[x]<[y]$ iff $x<y$ (it is easy to see this is independent of the representatives of the equivalence classes chosen).  Now for each equivalence class $y\in Y$ pick a representative $f(y)\in X$.  We then get a bijection $g:Y\times\mathbb{Z}\to X$ sending $(f(y),n)$ to the $n$th successor of $f(y)$.  Equipping $Y\times \mathbb{Z}$ with the lexicographic order, it is easy to see that $g$ is in fact an isomorphism.

So, every such $X$ is isomorphic to $Y\times\mathbb{Z}$ with the lexicographic order for some totally ordered set $Y$.  Conversely, if $Y$ is any totally ordered set, then every element of $Y\times\mathbb{Z}$ has a successor and a predecessor.  Moreover, if you start with $Y\times\mathbb{Z}$ and take the set of equivalence classes as described above, you get a totally ordered set that is canonically isomorphic to $Y$.  So the isomorphism classes of such $X$ are in bijection with the isomorphism classes of totally ordered sets $Y$.

Orders of this type are sometimes called "discrete total orders without endpoints".  They are a basic example in model theory, and in particular the first order theory of nonempty discrete total orders without endpoints is complete (so all the nonempty examples are elementarily equivalent).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.